# Emscripten, Embind, Error: no instance of constructor

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, embind

I am trying to convert classes (and structs) from C++ to Javascript using Emscripten.
For this I want to use Embind. I am trying to convert a very simple example but even with this example I am getting an error.
My Code:

```
#include "C:\\Emscripten\\emscripten\\1.30.0\\system\\include\\emscripten\\bind.h"

using namespace emscripten;

class AddTest
{
public:
    static unsigned int addTest(unsigned int stepCount);

};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(AddTest)
{
    class_<AddTest>("AddTest")
        .constructor<>()
        .class_function("addTest", &AddTest::addTest)
        ;
}
```

With this code, it gets me an error:

> "Error: no instance of constructor "class_BaseSpecifier::class_[with ClassType=AddTest, >BaseSpecifier=internal::NoBaseClass]" matches the argument list

An example for using Embind is given here:
https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#classes

I am just not able to spot the difference between the example and my code.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Looks like Emscripten wants a constructor. Have you tried making a dummy `AddTest(){}` constructor to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I did. Then    .constructor<>() gives me a "too few arguments for class template "constructor" error.

If I insert a parameter in the constructor like "int number", I am getting a "type name is not allowed" error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake. I forgot to specify

> --bind

in both the Clang C/C++ and Emcc Linker Properties under "Command Line".

Just have to fix the several other issues now :D

Comment: Indeed, here is the documentation from emscripten https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#embind